# `sscanf` not reading doubles properly when compiled locally

Tags: c++, cmake, scanf

I've been given some C++ code which (among other things) reads filenames and parses them using `sscanf`. However, despite using `%lf` for parsing, sscanf parses the first double truncated, and then fails to parse the rest of the string.

The offending code segment is:

```
        int row, col;
        double camx, camy;
        char ext[64];
        char inp[64] = "out_00_00_-381.909271_1103.376221.png";
        int ret = sscanf(inp, //files[i].toStdString().c_str(),
                         "out_%d_%d_%lf_%lf%s", &row, &col, &camy, &camx, ext);
```

I get the following parse:

```
ret=3
row=0, col=0
camy=-381
camx=[gibberish]
ext=[gibberish]
```

More confusingly, if I run the same code segment in repl.it, it works perfectly.

I'm compiling using CMake on Ubuntu 20.04, GCC 9.4.0 x86_64-linux-gnu. I don't fully understand CMake (since someone else gave me this repo), but I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

QT5_WRAP_CPP(lf_renderer_HEADERS_MOC LFViewWidget.h LFViewWindow.h)

add_executable(task5_lf_renderer main.cpp LFViewWindow.cpp LFViewWidget.cpp LightFieldRenderer.cpp ${lf_renderer_HEADERS_MOC})
target_compile_features(task5_lf_renderer PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
target_link_libraries(task5_lf_renderer ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets) #Qt5::OpenGL
```

where this file is `LightFieldRenderer.cpp` in the `add_executable()` call.

I suspect the issue is that some compile flags are being set/unset somewhere which is causing this to compile differently on my machine. Any pointers to where I should look would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're correct, I got them the wrong way around in the output. Fixed.

Comment: Your system localization seems to expect commas as floating points.

Comment: @273K Any idea how to check or change the localisation being used? If I print a floating-point to cout, I get periods not commas as the decimal mark.

Comment: @273K You're right! If I change the filenames to use commas instead of periods it gets parsed correctly.
I'm still interested: how do you check/set this localisation?